Why does deep learning stops in this video classfication lstm model?
I don't know why this model doesn't work. Number of video(grayscaled, 100 Frames) is 36 and GPU(Colab T4) is 15GB. Even 1 epoch doesn't increase.  Is this memory size insufficient to execute this model? If so, how much memory do you think it is needed? If not, is there another problem?
y shape (36,)
x shape (36, 100, 110, 100, 1)
Model: "sequential"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ time_distributed (TimeDistributed)   │ (4, 100, 110, 100, 8)       │             136 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ time_distributed_1 (TimeDistributed) │ (4, 100, 27, 25, 8)         │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ time_distributed_2 (TimeDistributed) │ (4, 100, 5400)              │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ lstm (LSTM)                          │ (4, 32)                     │         695,424 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense (Dense)                        │ (4, 16)                     │             528 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_1 (Dense)                      │ (4, 1)                      │              17 │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
 Total params: 696,105 (2.66 MB)
 Trainable params: 696,105 (2.66 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError


Implement gradient accumulation to reduce the memory required for training.If possible, use model parallelism or distributed training techniques.
